# Register author, facebook connect, publish posts from front end

Tags: custom-field, facebook, profiles, user-registration

I need little help to navigate me to the right method in these six steps.

1. Need a facebook login, which when you connect you register in the site like a author.
2. You have a register form to register like a author.
3. Post a post with all the categories and tag what the author wants - here i need many custom fields because it is a  recipe (preparation time, number portions, cooking type, ingredients etc.) .
4. Profile of the author in the front end. List of the posts which the author posted before.
5. Forgotten password functionality.
6. Search on the custom fields.

What is your opinion and what is the best solution? These custom fields can be categories or tags, i need opinions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The _six_ assorted things is hardly a “little” matter. :) Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in help on what types of questions work well here.

Comment: You are right, but regards of my specifics i need the whole cocktail because when the questions are separated or drop to lower level coding the answers will be not correct and it will be hard to collect all the guides in one thing. So someone if has expirience with those things it will be best to be in one post it will be more helpful to me.